# Swift ViewModel with associated type for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, protocols, associated-types

I have the following protocols and ViewModel

```
class ViewModel1 {}
class ViewModel2 {}

protocol CellViewModelType {
    typealias ViewModel
    func bind(vm:ViewModel)
}

class TVC1 : UITableViewCell, CellViewModelType {
    typealias ViewModel = ViewModel1
    func bind(vm:ViewModel)
}

class TVC2 : UITableViewCell, CellViewModelType {
    typealias ViewModel = ViewModel2
    func bind(vm:ViewModel)
}
```

This setup lets me bind a ViewModel to a TableViewCell class.
But the point where I am struggling is the binding itself:

```
// error: Protocol 'CellViewModelType' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(item.0, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellViewModelType
cell.bind(someViewModelReference)
```

the only workaround I came up so far is to use dynamic dispatch (`performSelector`), I was wondering if there is a way to take call the method directly without using the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do doesn't actually make sense. As the error says you want to cast to a protocol that have an associated type and currently there is no way of providing that type while doing a cast and without a type the casted cell wouldn't know what type of objects it can take as arguments for `bind` function. You should check if your cell is of type `TVC1`  or `TVC2` using `is` keyword and cast to that. Then you can just call `bind` on the casted reference.